# Diamond problem

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I was going through the diamond problem and thought will work on various scenarios. And this is one among them which I was working on.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class MainBase{

    public:
    int mainbase;
    MainBase(int i):mainbase(i){}
    void geta()
    {
        cout<<"mainbase"<<mainbase<<endl;
    }
};
class Derived1: public MainBase{

    public:
    int derived1;
    int mainbase;
    Derived1(int i):MainBase(i),derived1(i) {mainbase = 1;}
    public:
    void getderived1()
    {
        cout<<"derived1"<<derived1<<endl;
    }

};
class Derived2: public MainBase{

    public:
    int derived2;
    int mainbase;
    Derived2(int i):MainBase(i),derived2(i){mainbase = 2;}
    public:
    void getderived2()
    {
        cout<<"derived2"<<derived2<<endl;
    }
};
class Diamond: public Derived1, public Derived2{

    public:
    int diamond;
    int mainbase;
    Diamond(int i,int j, int x):Derived1(j),Derived2(x),diamond(i){mainbase=3;}
    public:
    void getdiamond()
    {
        cout<<"diamond"<<diamond<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Diamond d(4,5,6);
//    cout<< d.MainBase::mainbase;
    cout<<"tested"<<endl;
    cout<<d.mainbase;
    cout<<d.Derived2::mainbase<<endl;
    cout<<d.Derived1::mainbase<<endl;
    /*cout<<d.Derived2::MainBase::mainbase<<endl;
    cout<<d.Derived1::MainBase::mainbase<<endl;*/
}
```

I am now wondering how to I access MainBase class mainbase variable? Any inputs.

Comment: Fix the code, please. Select it all and hit 010101.

Comment: Indeed, it's a nightmare to look at. :(

Comment: The diamond problem:  "In object-oriented programming languages with multiple inheritance and knowledge organization, the diamond problem is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If a method in D calls a method defined in A (and does not override the method), and B and C have overridden that method differently, then from which class does it inherit: B, or C?" source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do what you have done there:

```
cout<<d.Derived2::MainBase::mainbase<<endl;
cout<<d.Derived1::MainBase::mainbase<<endl;
```

But, it might not do what you are trying to achieve. Possibly, you should be using `virtual` inheritance? What you have means there will be two copies of the `MainBase` members in your object, one for each inheritance track.

(From MSDN).

> When a base class is specified as a
>   virtual base, it can act as an
>   indirect base more than once without
>   duplication of its data members. A
>   single copy of its data members is
>   shared by all the base classes that
>   use it as a virtual base.

Probably something like this will suit you better:

```
class Derived1: virtual public MainBase{
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't compile, there is an ambiguity when referring to Mainbase as a base of a Diamond instance. You need to use *virtual* in the derived classes (Derived1, Derived2) to resolve this ambiguity by allowing them to share a single instance of base class, like this:

```
class Derived1: virtual public Mainbase {
/* do your thing here*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it like this from the `Diamond` class:

```
Diamond::foo() {
    Mainbase::mainbase = 0;
}
```

Assuming that your code compiles properly in the first place.  See [Michael Foukarakis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149530/michael-foukarakis) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264304/diamond-problem/1264366#1264366) for more about compilation.  Also, see this excellent article from DDJ: ["Multiple Inheritance Considered Useful"](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184402074) about how to do this correctly.